# Maven Archetype - Generate Dirs Hierarchy Without Project Name

Tags: maven, hierarchy, archetypes, generate

The package name in the class will be generated correctly, but the generated dirs hierarchy always includes the project name which is wrong as shown below, how to avoid it?

```
package ${groupId};

public class Main {

}
```

-

```
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>        
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.java</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

[image]

Comment: What will you achieve by saving few characters to type more ?

Comment: Why do you want the groupId as package name?

Comment: @Shailesh Pratapwar, I'm working on a generator engine

Comment: @JF Meier, I'm working on a generator engine

Comment: @AbdullahAlDokhi What do you mean by that? Why not use the standard package name?